# Strange behavior with volatile write on class member vs struct member

Tags: c#, .net, performance, struct, volatile

I'm developing a component which needs a `long` type with volatile semantics.
As there's no `volatile long` in .NET, I created a simple wrapper type which handles the read/write access using `Volatile` class.
I was unsure whether I should go with a class or struct so I decided to test them both and I ran across a very strange behavior.

Here's the test code:

```
internal class Program
{
    private class VolatileLongClass
    {
        private long value;

        public long Value
        {
            get { return Volatile.Read(ref value); }
            set { Volatile.Write(ref this.value, value); }
        }
    }

    private struct VolatileLongStruct
    {
        private long value;

        public long Value
        {
            get { return Volatile.Read(ref value); }
            set { Volatile.Write(ref this.value, value); }
        }
    }

    private static void Main()
    {
        const int iterations = 10;
        var totalTime = 0L;
        for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            var volatileLong = new VolatileLongClass(); //<-- change to VolatileLongStruct
            for (var j = 0L; j < 10 * 1000 * 1000; j++)
                volatileLong.Value = j;

            var msElapsed = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Ms Elapsed = {0}", msElapsed);
            totalTime += msElapsed;
        }
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Avg = {0:N2}", (double) totalTime / iterations);
    }
}
```

The output I get for VolatileLongStruct:

```
Ms Elapsed = 109
Ms Elapsed = 109
Ms Elapsed = 109
Ms Elapsed = 109
Ms Elapsed = 109
Ms Elapsed = 109
Ms Elapsed = 109
Ms Elapsed = 109
Ms Elapsed = 109
Ms Elapsed = 109
Avg = 109.00
```

The above output for struct is consistent. However, the output for VolatileLongClass is:

```
Ms Elapsed = 17558   <-- ***
Ms Elapsed = 105
Ms Elapsed = 105
Ms Elapsed = 105
Ms Elapsed = 105
Ms Elapsed = 105
Ms Elapsed = 17541   <-- ***
Ms Elapsed = 105
Ms Elapsed = 105
Ms Elapsed = 105
Avg = 3,593.90
```

As you can see there's a substantial time difference for some iterations. The exact iteration(s) which takes an abnormal time varies slightly but there's a consistent problem with at least one of the iterations.

Can someone shed some light as to why would a volatile write take (sometimes) longer on a class member than on a struct member?

By the way, the above result were produced with .Net 4.5 and Release build

Comment: I just tried your code, and I'm not seeing the same effects.

Comment: 'On a multiprocessor system, a volatile write operation ensures that a value written to a memory location is immediately visible to all processors. A volatile read operation obtains the very latest value written to a memory location by any processor. These operations might require flushing processor caches, which can affect performance.' - msdn.com

Comment: @GrantThomas Correct - it can't because it can only be used for types which can guarantee atomic reads and writes.

Comment: Incidentally, it's amazing how much faster it is in x64!

Comment: Of course, has to be mentioned: mutable `struct`s are evil.

Comment: Are you sure that your testing allocates both on heap? Have you tried to run both examples at once (in one run)?

Comment: My guess is the very long iterations are the ones where the garbage collector is doing a collection.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer agree 100% with your statement. But, has to be mentioned, there are exceptions to every rule ;)

Comment: A fundamental flaw in your assumptions is that you think you measured the time needed by Volatile.Write().  That is not the case, you *also* measure how long your thread didn't run on the processor because another thread had a higher priority.

Comment: @user35443 The MSDN docs are incorrect. Volatile does not mean "flush value" or "get the very latest value". Volatile only ensures acquire fence on reads and release fence on writes.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer I agree. But in this case it's perfectly reasonable to use struct as the idea is to provide volatile semantics to a long type (which is defined as struct itself)

Comment: @HansPassant Of course the time measured in not Volatile.Write() exclusively and includes everything else running on the machine. However, I ran the test many times when the computer is pretty much idle and the results are consistent. Also note that the time diff is too big to account for other threads, giving the machine is idle.

Comment: @Servy Please note that volatileLong is allocated in the outer loop, not inside the tight loop so there are at best 10 class/struct allocations (not considering compiler/JIT optimizations) - hardly something which would require a GC. Nonetheless, I have memory profiled the program and 70% of the memory allocated was the strings printed out to the console.

Comment: @user2497508 'The MSDN docs are incorrect'. . . . . . . . . . . . 
Of course.

Answer (score 1):

The time difference is most likely a consequence of the `var volatileLong = new VolatileLongClass();` within the loop; that statement causes the compiler to--once--allocate space to hold a `VolatileLongClass` reference, and then on each pass through the loop create a new object and store a reference into that location.  By contrast, the statement `var volatileLong = new VolatileLongStruct();` causes the compiler to--once--allocate space to hold a `VolatileLongStruct` instance, and then on each pass through the loop mutate that pre-existing instance by zeroing out all its data (using normal, rather than volatile, writes).

Note that if code will require structs fields to have particular multi-thread semantics, such fields should often be made public, and the struct should be regarded as being a group of variables stuck together with duct tape [e.g. `public struct IntPair {public int V1,V2;} IntPair myPair;` should be regarded as creating two separate variables `myPair.V1` and `myPair.V2`].  Since a struct *is*, in fact, a combination of variables stuck together with duct tape, and since any other abstraction presented by a struct whose size isn't 1, 2, or 4 bytes is bound to be "leaky" especially with regard to multi-thread behavior, it's better for a struct to present itself as what it is, than to pretend to be something it isn't.

Comment: When you say a new instance of VolatileLongClass is created on each pass, I assume you mean each pass of the outer loop right? If so, I agree with you but then only 10 objects are created in total which in completely negligible. If you refer to the inner loop (that is 10,000,000 objects are created on each of cycle) then please explain why as memory profiling doesn't support this claim.

Comment: @user2497508: Sorry... I misread your code.  Still, I think the point about structure properties still stands.  There are some occasions when it may make sense for struct members to use atomic primitives, but such usage requires that one avoid (or be very cautious with) any operations that read or write the structure as a whole (if it's necessary to copy it, use a static `copy` method that takes both the source and destination as `ref` parameters).